# Why does increasing the length of suspension strings increases a bifialr pendulum period of oscillation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Given that:

$$ T=\frac{ 2 \pi r \sqrt{ L } }{ \sqrt{3g} } \frac{1}{D} $$

where L stands for the length of suspension springs. What is the physics behind the correlation between the period of a bifilar pendulum and the length of its suspension strings?

Comment: It is easy to handle with screw drivers of long length than shorter ones. The same is the reason.

Comment: That is for same amount of force but accelerations i.e, angular accelerations vary, hence time also varies with length.